# Access GMail account with Thunderbird without POP/IMAP access?

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

IMAP/POP access to my school google mail account will soon be disabled.

Is there a way to access a google mail account using Thunderbird without IMAP or POP?

Answer (score 0):

The only method for accessing gmail without using IMAP or POP, is via a browser using
Web-mail.

However, this will not work if the school can suspend your account.

In that case, your only option will be to backup a snapshot of your data by using
[Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout).

See for details the article
[How to Back Up All Your Gmail Emails (Complete Guide)](https://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/back-up-gmail-emails-complete-guide--cms-30042).